# Scrolling Text box not receiving updates without focus

Tags: vb.net, xaml

I have a producer/consumer connection that is sending commands to a remote device and waiting for a prompt to listen for a response.

When a response is received, an event is fired and the received text is pushed to a scrolling text box as a new line.

Most of the time this works fine and the messages are displayed.  However when running a version of my code without the debugger attached, the text output does not update, or sometimes will update very very slowly unless a user is actively clicking on that area of the form, in which case it works as expected.

I assume this has something to do with user focus, but I'm not sure. The issue never seems to present itself when debugging.

Comment: Tidied up the language

Answer (score 1):

`Repaint` the form after updating the text box. An easy assumption is that this happens automatically, but sometimes the operating system manages repaints with other priorities in mind. A manual repaint forces the issue.

I haven't got the IDE open in front of me, but from memory it should be possible to `repaint` the text box, rather than entire form - this could help with flicker if your text box changes frequently or the form is large and complicated.

Comment: I'll give it a try